# TikZ/PGF - how to draw a node as a line (rectangle with zero height)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to a sequence of nodes, finished by a line. I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{st1}=[circle, inner sep=1.5pt, draw]
\tikzstyle{st2}=[rectangle, inner xsep=2pt, inner ysep=0pt, draw] 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, level distance=10pt, every node/.style={st1}]
        \path node{} child {node{} child {node[st2]{}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but this gives [image: TikZ_ex_nodes_v1], i.e. the node has some height. Is there some (simple) way to make the last node into a line? If possible using definition of `st2`, so it it simple to use.

The closest thing I managed is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{st1}=[circle, inner sep=1.5pt, draw]
\tikzset{st2/.style={rectangle, inner sep=-2pt, draw=none}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, level distance=10pt, every node/.style={st1}]
        \path node{} child {node{} child {node[st2]{\textbf{--}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but this is more a dirty hack. In addition, it needs needs having `\textbf{--}` in every such node .. and it won't work if I ever need the sequence to be horizontal.

Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that I probably should have used `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`, as explained in [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372). However, I leave it as it is, since it works and the accepted answer uses this as well..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key is to give a `minimum height` to that node. Here you can see the result with `0pt` and `.4pt` respectively:

[image: Result]

**UPDATE**: Also, in order to get a better control of the width of the node, use `minimum width` instead of `inner xsep`. Analogously, you better use `minimum width` for the circular nodes too, instead of `inner sep=1.5pt`. This way you can play with the size of the nodes, as for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{st1}=[circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt, draw]
\tikzstyle{st2}=[rectangle, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=0pt, minimum width=4pt, draw] 

\tikzstyle{st1b}=[circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=6pt, draw]
\tikzstyle{st2b}=[rectangle, minimum height=.4pt, minimum width=6pt, inner sep=0pt, draw] 

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, level distance=10pt, every node/.style={st1}]
        \path node{} child {node{} child {node[st2]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, level distance=10pt, every node/.style={st1b}]
        \path node{} child {node{} child {node[st2b]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: And once more thanks for the update, that was a good point.

Comment: This works correctly only for solid lines. What if you want to have a node as a dotted or dashed line?